# Add link under the active theme in the Appearances page

Tags: wordpress, themes

In the theme selection page, links are shown below the active theme which shows its capabilities. Most of the time these are *Widgets*, *Menus*, and a *Theme Options* link if you run `add_theme_page()`.

Since I created my own top-level menu and didn't use add_theme_page(), my path redirects to `admin.php?page=chosen-slug` instead of `themes.php?page=chosen-slug` and there is no *Theme Options* link in the Appearance section. Is there a way I can still display that link to show that my theme has options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a jQuery solution will have to do for now. It's not my first choice but at least it works.

PHP:

```
// Create the theme options link
add_action("admin_menu", "setup_theme_admin_menus"); 
function setup_theme_admin_menus(){
    add_theme_page('', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'sample-slug', '');
}
```

jQuery:

```
// Redirect link in Appearance to your top-level menu
$('#current-theme div.theme-options a[href="themes.php?page=sample-slug"]').attr('href', 'admin.php?page=sample-slug');

/*
 * Hide the link created by add_theme_page(). Use each() since our <li> has no
 * name and this makes sure the script always works even if its position changes.
 */
$('#menu-appearance a[href="themes.php?page=sample-slug"]').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```